# What is the point of using custom defined epsilon to avoid errors from operations on floating point numbers?

Tags: java, floating-point

While solving the following problem from [CTCI](http://www.crackingthecodinginterview.com) book:

> Given a two-dimensional graph with points on it, find a line which passes the most number of points.

I came across this [solution](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition/tree/master/Java/Ch%2016.%20Moderate/Q16_14_Best_Line). It essentially computes the slopes and y-intercepts of all possible segments, hashes the results and determines the max of identical ones. The problem arises if we use `double` type for storing coordinates because in order to compute the slope we need to compute `(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. So in order to avoid incorrect results the solution introduces `epsilon` to be 0.0001 for example and converts a `double` number using the function below.

```
public static double floorToNearestEpsilon(double d) {
        int r = (int) (d / epsilon);
        double tmp = ((double) r) * epsilon;
        return tmp;
}
```

Eventually, the algorithm compares keys with their "epsilonized" in order to determine equivalent lines using `isEquivalent` function from [here](https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition/blob/master/Java/Ch%2016.%20Moderate/Q16_14_Best_Line/Line.java).

I'm wondering: if problems in general can occur with floating types division and `floorToNearestEpsilon` still uses division on doubles then why would this approach somehow resolve possible floating type issues?

Also how common is such approach?

**Note:** in the GitHub code `epsilon = 0.5` however in the original book `epsilon = 0.0001`.

Comment: Could you edit to add a problem statement from CTCI? We may be looking at a sub-optimal solution (also known as "a hack" :-).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight edited the problem statement

Comment: Does the problem statement in the book supply coordinates as `int`s or as `double`s?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it doesn't say in the book whether the coordinates are `int` or `double`

Comment: It sounds like a kuldge. Quantizing results like this—assigning slopes to buckets and then comparing the buckets instead of the slopes—attempts to decrease false negatives (incorrect reports of slopes being unequal because floating-point errors made them unequal even though the exact mathematical slopes are equal). But it increases false positives (incorrect reports of equality because the buckets are the same even though the exact slopes differ). There can be situations in which is know false positives do not occur (e.g., because the domain is limited and analysis can show the errors stay…

Comment: … within certain bounds) or not harmful (e.g., because they are screened out later). But, to be a proper solution, that needs to be documented. Also, the quantizing can fails, as when two calculated slopes differ, and should be equal mathematically, but they fall on different sides of a bucket border.